# Copy to clipboard buttons

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I want to create "copy to clipboard" buttons to work on our sharepoint. They should be placed in a few different places, and what I need to copy is some text from from a specific field on the page (ex. a list of emails).

I know, I can just select the text and copy it, but we do it quite often, so having a button that automatically copies the text to the clipboard would be very useful.

I did manage to create one in a Script Editor, where I pasted the whole code below (which I found on the internet)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("pasteTarget").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    this.value = "";
});


function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
      var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = "Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy."
    } else {
        msg = "Text copied to the clipboard."
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
      // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
          succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}


}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <input id="copyTarget" value="Some initial text"> <button id="copyButton">Copy</button><br><br>
<span id="copyTarget2">Some Other Text</span> <button id="copyButton2">Copy</button><br><br>
<input id="pasteTarget"> Click in this Field and hit Ctrl+V to see what is on clipboard<br><br>
<span id="msg"></span><br>



</body>

</html>
```

But we have main problems with it:
1) it reloads the page every time we click the "copy" button
2) it is not very elegant and friendly, when we think about updating our documents

I would be very grateful for any hints you may have for me, on how to make it work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project may help: [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Comment: Hi

I've found it, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Let's say I'm not really good with javascript, and only starting to figure out the sharepoint functionalities. If you have any guidelines how to use it, I'd be grateful

Comment: Please, see the explanation on the main page. Here is the code: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/target-input.html

Comment: Ok, that helped. I've managed to make the buttons just the way I want it, but they still refresh my page in sharepoint. Is there any way to eliminate that?

Comment: May be there are other handlers on them. Possibly try to remove hyperlinks from your buttons.